# Placing subfigure argument at the distance below the figure

Tags: floats, formatting, subfloats

In my `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}` I'm using the following

```
\begin{figure}[]
\centering

\subfigure[text A]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{a.pdf}}
\subfigure[text B}]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{b.pdf}}

\caption[]
        { text C } 
\end{figure}
```

Note that 'text A' and 'text B' are places just below figures a.pdf and b.pdf, respectively. Could I somehow make the gap between 'text A' and a.pdf  larger?

Comment: You are so close then why not making the example compilable with dummy pictures. You can use `\Huge A` or `\Large A` instead of the pdf files.

Comment: Well, you have it already. Replace pdf files as you propose.

Comment: What I meant is a code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I understand

```
\begin{figure}[]
\centering

{\subfigcapskip = 20pt \subfigure[text A]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{a.pdf}}}
\subfigure[text B}]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{b.pdf}}

\caption[]
        { text C } 
\end{figure}
```